# ajax post dynamic table rows to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my code of JS/Jquery to generate table rows dynamically. But i am unable to send the table data to php using AJAX call.  i am getting the error called "Null value." Can anyone please help me out to resolve this issue whether i am missing out something in the ajax call. Thanks in advance.

```
function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";

 var itemno=document.getElementById("itemno_row"+no);
 var mnop=document.getElementById("mnop_row"+no);
 var nog=document.getElementById("nog_row"+no);
 var gwv=document.getElementById("gwv_row"+no);

 var itemno_data=itemno.innerHTML;
 var mnop_data=mnop.innerHTML;
 var nog_data=nog.innerHTML;
 var gwv_data=gwv.innerHTML;

 itemno.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='itemno_text"+no+"' value='"+itemno_data+"'>";
 mnop.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='mnop_text"+no+"' value='"+mnop_data+"'>";
 nog.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='nog_text"+no+"' value='"+nog_data+"'>";
 gwv.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='gwv_text"+no+"' value='"+gwv_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var itemno_val=document.getElementById("itemno_text"+no).value;
 var mnop_val=document.getElementById("mnop_text"+no).value;
 var nog_val=document.getElementById("nog_text"+no).value;
  var gwv_val=document.getElementById("gwv_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("itemno_row"+no).innerHTML=itemno_val;
 document.getElementById("mnop_row"+no).innerHTML=mnop_val;
 document.getElementById("nog_row"+no).innerHTML=nog_val;
 document.getElementById("gwv_row"+no).innerHTML=gwv_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none";
}

function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}

function add_row()
{
 var new_itemno=document.getElementById("new_itemno").value;
 var new_mnop=document.getElementById("new_mnop").value;
 var new_nog=document.getElementById("new_nog").value;
 var new_gwv=document.getElementById("new_gwv").value;

 var table=document.getElementById("itemTable");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='itemno_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_itemno+"</td><td id='mnop_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_mnop+"</td><td id='nog_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_nog+"</td><td id='gwv_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_gwv+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_itemno").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_mnop").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_nog").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_gwv").value="";
}
function insert_row()
{
 var itemno=document.getElementById("itemno_row").value;
 var mnop=document.getElementById("mnop_row").value;
 var nog=document.getElementById("nog_row").value;
 var gwv=document.getElementById("gwv_row").value;

 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'savedata.php',
  data:{
   insert_row:'insert_row',
   itemno:itemno,
   mnop:mnop,
   nog:nog,
   gwv:gwv
  },
  success:function(msg) {
   alert('wow' + msg);

  }
 });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm if `insert_row` param is received by savedata.php?

Comment: yes, but the empty data is been saved to mysql